# Besides ServersMan, any apps that can turn iPhone into an web/app server?

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation

I have read from  [Has anyone ever tried to use an iPhone as web server?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9012/has-anyone-ever-tried-to-use-an-iphone-as-web-server), there is an app called ServersMan  that can turn Phone into an web server. But it is not available in my local app store. Do you have suggestions of alternatives for turning iPhone into an web/app server?

Hopefully, it can provide tunneling-like function so that it can be used in 3G network.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can create US AppStore account and download it from another than local AppStore.
Alternatively it's possible if you jailbreak your iPhone, and have Cydia to install apache and php.

Answer (score 0):

ServersMan is not a web server It's a pseudo server. It merely lets you access files in its Local Storage over a WiFi network. If you want a full-fledged web server running on your iPhone, you're going to have to install Apache, and you'll most definitely have to be JailBroken. It's not as simple as you'd hope.